# My answer was converted into a comment. I thought I answered properly

Tags: support

My answer, https://money.stackexchange.com/a/63749/25694, was converted to a comment and I am not sure how to find the exact reason for it.

Comment: I think you could have said the same thing as well, or better, without the explicit reference to Best Buy -- it's enough to say that some stores do have a policy, announced or not, of offering a price guarantee and it's worth politely asking. (Occasionally the staff may have discretion to give you a partial discount even if that isn't the formal policy, which is part of why politeness helps. We recently got a discount at a hotel just for sympathizing and being helpful right after they had had to deal with a particularly annoying customer on the phone....)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I received a moderator flag that this was a better comment than answer. When I looked at it, the answer had no more details than others already posted, basically "ask." As Keshlam noted, the Best Buy reference wasn't helpful. Many US stores have this policy, but OP is in the Euro-zone.

Note, right now there are 8 answers posted, and probably only 3-4 are unique.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback and will make sure to keep your advice in mind for the future, thanks!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thanks for being respectful to hard working, volunteer moderators.    I look forward to reading your answers in the future.